# check if cell is empty OR has a value, AND cell in row isn't empty then assess as true or false

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to format a column so that if the column A cell is `NOT` empty, `AND` the column H cell is either empty `OR` `"no"`

```
=AND(NOT(ISBLANK($A$1:$A)), (OR(ISBLANK($H$1:$H)), (LOOKUP("no", $H$1:$H))))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**custom formula:** **`=IF((A1<>"")*((H1="")+(H1="no")),1)`**

[image: 0]